# Write a code which check sunday week rest and leaves all parts works fine except leave part

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper

I write a code which works all fine except only leave and part not working please suggest me something which may help me

```
function CF_WEEKRESTFormula return CHAR is
v_rest     number;
gaz_dt     number;
descr      varchar2(90);
gz_dt      date;
AT_P             VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT week_rest
  INTO   v_rest
  FROM   EMPLOYEES
  WHERE  employee_id1=:employee_id1
  AND    :ATT_DATE between :DATE1 and :DATE2;
  select gazzeted_date, description into gz_dt, descr 
  from gazzeted_days
  where gazzeted_date between :DATE1 and :DATE2;
  select ATT_PRESENT into AT_P 
  from PAY_IN_OUT
  where ATT_PRESENT = 'L' 
  AND  EMP_CODE=:employee_id1
  AND :ATT_DATE between :DATE1 and :DATE2;
  
  IF TO_CHAR( :ATT_DATE, 'D' ) = v_rest THEN
    RETURN 'WEEK REST';
  ELSIF
    :ATT_DATE = GZ_DT THEN 
    RETURN DESCR;
  ELSIF AT_P = TO_CHAR(:ATT_DATE) THEN 
    RETURN 'LEAVE';
    ELSE RETURN 'PRESENT';
  END IF;
  exception 
       when No_data_found 
         then return 'a';
END;
```

all working expcept this part

```
ELSIF AT_P = TO_CHAR(:ATT_DATE) THEN 
    RETURN 'LEAVE';
```

which checks where is L agt date of att_date if there is l then gives Leave att_date please suggest me something
regards

Answer (score 0):

- `AT_P` is `varchar2(10)`

  - you are selecting `ATT_PRESENT` into it, but we don't know its datatype - presumably, it is a string
  - as you're later comparing it to `:att_date`, that *string* probably represent some date value

    - if that's so, you shouldn't be doing it - always store dates into `DATE` datatype columns
- `:ATT_DATE` looks like a `DATE` datatype; is it? Or is it `VARCHAR2`?

  - if it is `DATE`, then applying `TO_CHAR` to it makes sense, but **format** is missing - you should provide it, and it should match the one returned into `at_p`
  - if it is `VARCHAR2`, then there's no use in `TO_CHAR`-ing it again

Therefore: I presume that - if you applied format to `:ATT_DATE`, something *positive* might happen. For example, if `:att_date = '03/08/2021'` (today's date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format):

```
elsif at_p = to_char(:att_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') then
  return 'leave';
```

Exact code depends on what is really stored into `at_p` and `:att_date`.

Comment: at_p store strings like `L` and ` P` and att_date have dates i want where date comes  equal to att_date = L then it return Leave  mean on 03/09/21 if att_present have `L` then it shows Leave else is Present and other all code is fine

Comment: Obviously, you can't compare L or P to ATT_DATE which represents a **date**, they will never match. Should it be e.g. `ELSIF AT_P = 'L' THEN return 'leave'`?

Comment: it gives all field with Leave I tried it first what i can do more for this please help me